# PHP GET ($_GET) always prints name of variable and not value

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, get

what I'm trying to do is get the value of the selected term from the autocomplete menu (ui.item.label), store it in a variable and send that value to my database. For that, I have another php file named "proceed.php", which connects us to the database and will insert the data into the table.

But I seem to be stuck at passing the variable "$selected" from *look* to *proceed* as no matter what I do, the browser displays *$vari*, that is, the variable passed here - `proceed1.php?var=$vari`

Backstory - You may notice that I have assigned the variable *vari* as apple. Yet, I see only *$vari* as the output on the browser and not apple.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you very much.

look.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#route" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php',
      select: function( event , ui ) {
      $selected=ui.item.label;}   
    });
  });
  $vari="apple";
  </script>

</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="look.css" media="screen" /> 
<body> 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="route">Router Name: </label>
  <input id="route">
  <br><br><br>
  <a href='proceed1.php?var=$vari' id=btn2 class="btn">Proceed</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

proceed.php

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'searchrouters';
//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
//get search term
$vari = $_GET['var'];
echo $vari;
?>
```

**UPDATE** :

Thank you, the solution provided in the comments worked. But now when I'm trying to get the variable *selected*'s value as :

```
 <?php
  $vari=$_GET['selected'];
 ?>
```

and then pass it in to the next page as :

```
<a href='proceed1.php?var=<?php echo $vari;?>' id=btn2 class="btn">Proceed</a>
```

I get the following error on the browser :

> Undefined index: selected in C:\wamp\www\look.php on line 19

Comment: What is `term` here? replace `term` with `var` it can be helped.

Comment: you declared php variable in jquery

Comment: Sorry about `term`. It was supposed to be var itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify you code in two places

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#route" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php',
      select: function( event , ui ) {
         $selected=ui.item.label;
         $('#btn2').attr({'href':'proceed1.php?var='+$selected});
       } 
    }); 
  });
  </script>
<?php
  $vari="apple";
?>
```

and `<a href="proceed1.php?term=<?php echo $vari;?>" id=btn2 class="btn">Proceed</a>`

and when you need to access the variable just use `$_GET['var']` 
Where ever you want to user php with HTML you need to user the `<?php php code here ?>`

here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paragchaure/ujn1n8h5/)

Comment: Hey, would you mind looking at the updated issue? Thanks

Comment: you need to user the `$selected` in $_GET['selected']?

Comment: I did that first. But the error persists saying Undefined index: $selected

Comment: So basically you need to send the option selected by autocomplete after click on the proceed button as a query string, Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need to do.

Comment: WOW. I could have never thought of that. Makes perfect sense.
Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome @hgnisitida :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare php variable in jquery.

try this

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#route" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php',
      select: function( event , ui ) {
      $selected=ui.item.label;}   
    });
  });
  </script>
<?php
  $vari="apple";
?>
```

and

```
<a href="proceed1.php?term=<?php echo $vari;?>" id=btn2 class="btn">Proceed</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change here remove `$vari="apple";` from `script` tag and use it inside php tag

```
<?php $vari="apple"; ?>
```

and get variable `$vari` like this

```
<a href="proceed1.php?term=<?php echo $vari;?>" id=btn2 class="btn">Proceed</a>
```